# Why does my fridge turn itself off?

Tags: repair, thermostat, refrigerator, appliances, compressor

My KitchenAid fridge intermittently turns off, and the only way to turn it back on is to turn off thermostat to off and then back to on (setting 1/2/3/4/5).

Any idea what is the issue?

Comment: We know the brand, how about the model & age? Are there any other signs or symptoms - odd noises, anything?

Comment: Age would be 15 years. No noises. Once I play with the thermostat, it works, then stops and doesn't start again.

Comment: And you confirmed that the temp inside is higher than it should be?

Comment: Yes - I kept a bowl of water in refrigerator. It became rock hard ice. Then in morning, it had melted. Then I turned on/off thermostat. It again became rock hard ice and then melted again once compressor stopped.

Comment: Rock hard ice?  Maybe the **temperature sensor** isn't connected or is malfunctioning so the fridge thinks it isn't cold enough and keeps running until an overload/frost/safety sensor shuts it down.

Comment: How can it be fixed? How much will it cost?

Comment: Since we have no idea where in the world you live or where you're buying parts, it's impossible for us to tell you how much it costs. I would suggest you search the internet for "appliance repair parts", then pick a site or two and search for your brand & model of fridge. Most have parts diagrams indicating what the parts are called & where they go, with links to the parts themselves. You can decide if you want to order & install based on your skills, or pay to have someone repair it for you. You may not even need parts, just the diagram to discover that something has been disconnected.

Comment: **15 years old** - then it's however much a new fridge costs. Otherwise it's however much a new fridge costs, shortly after however much it costs to fix this one.

Comment: water should not freeze inside the refrigerator compartment ... that should happen inside the freezer compartment

Comment: First guess the compressor is overheating or something is shutting it down that requires a hard reset, if pulling the plug will also get it to run again it’s probably not a DIY fix.